# Get link to an image on google image Wget

Tags: bash, wget, google-image-search

I am currently trying to make a Wallpaper randomiser. 
The rule that I have is to take the 9th image on google image from a random word selected and put it as the wallpaper. I am doing it on bash.

But when I do a `wget` on a google website, the common `href` for these link disappear and get replace (if I don't use the option `-k` they get replace by a # else they get replace by something that i can't read)

Here is my command:

```
wget -q -p -k --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0" -e robots=off  $address
```

where `$address` is:

```
address="https://www.google.fr/search?q=wallpaper+$word&safe=off&biw=1920&bih=880&tbs=isz:ex,iszw:1920,iszh:1080&tbm=isch&source=lnt"
```

the link that I want to obtain is like

```
href="/imgres/imgurl="<Paste here an url image>"
```

I have some new information.

In fact google seems to change his url with javascript and other client technologies. Then i need some wget copy that interpret javascript before. Do some one know this?

Comment: Since you'll have to deal with javascript (I assume) to pull this off, you'll have to look at a tool besides wget to pull this off. Perhaps [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/)

Comment: the problem is that i have limited tools (like i can't install phantom js on my session) so i need to use common tools. Some people suggested me python. And look for google's Ajax request.

Comment: It seems to me that a company like Google would support folks that don't have javascript even for image search. Perhaps load up a browser and shut off javascript and perform the search to see how the site is structured (and if it's navigable) without js enabled. Then you might be able to replicate that navigation with wget or curl.